# What is this component next to the IR LEDs on an Amcrest Camera?

Tags: identification, components, camera

I recently disassembled an Amcrest IP Camera and found this sensor next to the IR LEDs.  It doesn't look like a photosensitive resistor which has a zig-zag pattern.

Can someone explain what it is?

[image: photo of camera with unknown component marked]

Comment: The bluish plastic I've seen before in photodiodes/phototransistors.  It's a dye used to make the plastic opaque to wavelengths you don't want to be measuring but transparent to the ones you do want (IR is like 800nm-2000nm or thereabouts).   It could be used to measure the output of the other lights and help keep them at some particular brightness maybe?   or stop them from getting TOO bright, etc...   Notice its surrounded by opaque material, possibly suggesting it is measuring light reflected off the target rather than directly measuring what the LED's are sending.

Comment: It's probably a photodiode to measure ambient light to control the IR LEDs.  The component you're thinking of is a photoresistor.  A photodiode is probably used instead of a photoresistor because photoresistors use cadmium which is a hazardous substance and because the spectral response of the photodiode is closer to the LEDs' emitted wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to a light sensor phototransistor (could be a chip too). As in [this](https://www.tme.com/in/en/details/l-93dp3bt/phototransistors/kingbright-electronic/) Kingbright one:

[image]

Datasheet [here](https://www.tme.com/Document/4c1edb433cf7ed8639d339dfd904e2a8/l-932p3bt.pdf)

The ones with light blue epoxy roll off to 20% response at around 750nm vs. 470nm for clear epoxy, so they are mainly sensitive to IR.

[Clear epoxy phototransistor](https://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/WP7113P3C.pdf)

[image]
[Blue epoxy phototransistor](https://www.kingbright.com/attachments/file/psearch/000/00/00/L-3DP3BT(Ver.16).pdf)

[image]

The style of CdS light sensor with a serpentine pattern that you are referring to looks like this (image from [here](https://elmwoodelectronics.ca/products/photo-cell-cds-photoresistor)):

[image]

They are prohibited in many jurisdictions (and have been for many years now) because they contain toxic cadmium and there are viable alternatives.